# does php file size matter?

Tags: php, performance, filesize

i have a file of php codes

does it matter if this files size is **50kb** every script is uncompressed like this

```
a
b
c
  c1
    c1c
       c1c1

       c1c2

       c1c3
d
  d1
  d2
  d3
  d4
```

and it is **13kb** if compressed like this

```
a
b
c c1 c1c c1c1 c1c2 c1c3
d d1 d2 d3 d4
```

if it is **uncompressed** it is readable and faster to edit but if **compressed** it is still easier to edit for me but sometimes i get lost in it

i want to know if it affects the speed of the script and the speed on the client side because i want it to be as fast as possible

and is it the same for php-html merges like

```
<tag value="<?php
     a
     b
     c
?>"></tag>
```

and

```
<tag value="<?php a b c ?>"></tag>
```

Comment: It does not matter much if you divided the files in small sizes.If you have one file which is larger in size obviously it matters.

Comment: @CodeBreaker some files are 5mb in size and when compressed they become 1mb

Comment: It's fine with 5 to 10 MB but it can't be like 40 MB 50 MB @Joe

Comment: If your code files are 5 meg in size there are other issues at play! Most files with code are well under 100k and even those that size are fairly rare.